# How to read kudu table periodically and cache it in flink which is further used as filtering

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, apache-kudu

I am very new to Flink. I have to create a pipeline that will read streaming data from Kafka, read a kudu table every 10 mins (refresh kudu table data every 10 mins), perform join operation, and then finally store to another kudu table. In spark we can read the kudu table as a data frame and then cache that data frame but how to do the same thing in Flink?

Also, it will be really helpful if I get some examples regarding reading from Kudu to flink.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/kudu/current/source-connector/overview.html?

Comment: @DavidAnderson , the link you provided is a Kudu source connector for Kafka. But I need to read kudu table in Flink.

Comment: You indicated that you are already using Kafka for this application, so I assumed it would be workable to use Kafka connect as a way to get the Kudu data into Flink.